# Deleting Branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch

What is the difference between `git branch -d branch_to_delete` and `git branch -D brach_to_delete`?

I have performed this two commands on different occasions. one I performed when a branch was not fully merged.

Answer (score 2):

`branch -d` will issue an error if it's not fully merged, i.e. changes would be lost if it  is really deleted.

`branch -D` will ignore this and delete it even if it's not fully merged.

So you'd better use the first form, and the second only if you know you'll never need the branch again.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't allow deleting unmerged branches with -d flag, to make sure data is not lost accidentally and throws an error to notify that you're trying to delete an unmerged branch.

If you are completely sure what you are doing you can use -D.

-D flag is mostly used after merging branches and when those branches are no more needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have remote branch is "test". First delete remote git branch by using command:

```
git push origin :test
```

Delete local branch if code is merged:

```
git branch -d test
```

if branch code is not merged:

```
git brancg -D test
```

You can have a look to [push and delete remote branches](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html) for more details.